# mdadm コマンドが Device or resource busy となり RAID が組めない

Tags: linux, raid

mdadmを使ってソフトウェアRAIDを組みたいのですが、

```
[root@raid ~]# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-device=2 /dev/sd[ab]1
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda1: Device or resource busy
```

と表示されてしまい、うまくいきません。

/dev/sda1はブートドライブなのですが、どうしたらRAIDを組めるでしょうか。

ブートドライブを含まない場合はRAIDを組めることを確認しました。

検証しているのはCentOS7です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat の Knowledgebase に情報がありました。
[How do I convert my root disk to RAID1 after installation of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2390831)
(サブスクリプション契約が必要)

`--raid-device=2 /dev/sd[ab]1` だと、どちらのデータも初期化されてしまうので、`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-device=2 missing /dev/sdb1` で新しいディスクのみで RAID1 を構築し、rsync などでデータをコピーし、コピー先のデータ(sdb1)を正として、`mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1` で追加します(sda1 のデータは捨てる)。

LVM だともう少し複雑です。

他、/etc/fstab, /etc/default/grub の修正、grub2-mkconfig, grub2-install (sda, sdb とも), dracut の実行が必要です。

Answer (score 2):

基本的には、ファイルシステムをいじる場合はマウントを解除して行います。
`/dev/sda1`はどこかにマウントされているのではないでしょうか。

ルートディレクトリなどの重要な場所にマウントされている場合は、そのシステムの動作中にはアンマウントできないと思います。
ライブCDなりの別のパーティションなりから、別のシステムを起動して作業します。